# WebClient GET/POST without blocking UI

Tags: c#, winforms, asynchronous

I would like to make non blocking GET and POST requests. I've managed to solve it with `BackgroundWorker`, but I need your help to achieve it using tasks.

```
public Task<string> Post(Uri uri, string data)
{
    return _webClient.UploadStringTaskAsync(uri, data);
}

public Task<string> Get(Uri uri)
{
    return _webClient.DownloadStringTaskAsync(uri);
}
```

I need the requests to run sequentially. What's the proper way to implement this? Flag methods with `async` and `await` them? Wait for each task using `Task.WaitAll()`?

An example of what I'm after:

```
Task<string> loginTask = Post("login", data);
// wait for webrequest to complete and make use of response string

// use data from first request in a new request:
Task<string> someOtherRequest = Get("details");
```

Comment: Your example of what you are after doesn't compile. The Post method's first parameter is a Uri, but you pass a string instead.

Comment: @Zack It's just to get you an idea. Make a `new Uri(str)`

Comment: You need to put some effort into creating a good example if you want anyone to put time into trying to help you. :\

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't using HttpClient & async/await?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `await Task.Run()`:

```
await Task.Run(()=> { Run_UI_Blocking_Function(); });
```

For example:

In the `Post()` function, you can add this:

```
await Task.Run(()=> { PostString = Post(new Uri("url"), "data"); });
```

And in the 'Get()' function, you can add this:

```
await Task.Run(()=> { GetString = Get(new Uri("url")); });
```

You'd just need to add `async` to your calling function. Here's a completed example:

```
private async void btn_PostData_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await Task.Run(()=> { PostString = Post(new Uri("url"), "data"); }); 
}
```

Hope this helps. It's really short and sweet.

Comment: That just looks messy, especially when there's an HttpClient already plumbed for async.

Comment: It downloads async, but it doesn't stop the rest of the code from blocking the UI thread. He didn't post that code, and it could be doing a lot of other things. This gets around it.

Comment: Yes, but it's *messy*. Definitely wouldn't categorize it as short and sweet. If you know the HttpClient way of doing it, and update your answer to show that instead, I'll give you an upvote!

Comment: Perhaps it's messy, but this is a short and sweet solution from my perspective. :-) I haven't tried the HttpClient async method yet. Would you mind posting an example so that both of us could learn from you?

Answer (score -1):

You need to mark the method as async, and await the result.

```
public async Task<string> Get(Uri uri)
        {
        return await _webClient.DownloadStringTaskAsync(uri);
        }
```

You can also install the [Microsoft HttpClient library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Net.Http), which is already plumbed for async calls and may be a little lighter weight.

Comment: Hey! I knew that, but I totally forgot about it!. You're right, my method is definitely messy compared to yours. +1